# Send user to preferences on Android after button is clicked

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-preferences

I have an Android app which requires the user to be connected to the Internet. If the user is not online, the app shows an AlertDialog which says: "You have to be connected to the Internet to use this app". In that AlertDialog I have a button. Can I some how send the user to preferences, so the user can turn internet on and return to my app? So when the user returns I just run my methods to get the information from the services I use.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
    startActivity(new Intent(WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK));
```

EDIT: you could use:

```
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK), PICK_WIFI_REQUEST_CODE);
```

and then override:

```
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       //Check if you have internet
       //... proceed to next Activity
   }
```

Comment: Simple as that! Does the user return to my app after enabling wi-fi?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Intent using the current class activity and the WifiManager constant to search for network/pick a network.  Start the activity and wait for result.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity.this, WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK);
startActivityForResult(intent,1)
```